# How can i get rid of traces of deleted tables in sql (on cmd)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

[image]

I am using *cmd* for learning sql languages. However, when i drop the tables, they do not disappear, but stay with unknown names like the pictures.
I exactly used

`SQL> drop table <table name>;`

to drop them .
   what is wrong with this and how can i get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

It is the function of Recycle Bin.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN01511

If you want to delete the table pernamently you need to use the following command:

```
drop table 'table name' purge;
```

You can also delete this object from recycle bin after your command;

```
PURGE TABLE 'table name';
```

Comment: how can I get rid of them since their name is so complicated?

Comment: Let's say that your table is called "peter_tab" and you executed "delete table peter_tab". Now you can execute: "purge table peter_tab". You can also remove all tables from recycle bin by using "purge recyclebin"

Comment: Don't get into the habit of `drop table ... purge`. It's fine when you remember what you're doing, but one day you'll accidentally drop the wrong table and you'll really regret its absence from the recycle bin.

Comment: Thanx for the advice :)